# android webview css margin-left/right doesn't work

Tags: android, webview

I have some problem with content in webview

Simple webview:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/someWebview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I call that

```
WebView webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.someWebview);
webView.clearView();

webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, null, "utf-8", null);
```

and content looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>some</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>

  <style>
    *{margin:0; padding:0;}
    html, body{width:100%;}
  </style>
</head>



<body>
  <p style="width:50%; margin: 50px 0 0 100px; background-color: #0000ff">asdasd</p>
  <div style="width: 20%; margin-left: 50px; background-color:#ff0000; padding:0 50px;"><p style="background-color:#ffffff;">dfgdfg</p><div style="width:30%;margin-left: 50px;background-color:#1e1e1e;">dsdsd</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, problem is what margin-left does not work, but margin-top is ok.. how can I fix this? I can't use android:paddingLeft cause i need margin only some content not all of this

I can't add image to post, so uploaded them here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bNFR.png
first is desktop browser, second webview

**Update**

So guess I "solve" problem in my case with parsing html and adding container div's with paddings in places where I need, but this is bad hack and guess not all case can use this, so I think question still open - why margins left/right doesn't work?

Comment: Did you  forget to close the double quotes:
`<p style="width: 90%; margin: 100px 0 0 100px;">` ?

Comment: sorry this is just typo here, i'm edited it, but this isn't fix the problem